# Can't get Facebook multi-friend-selector working in Facebox

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, facebook

I'm trying to place the Facebook [multi-friend-selector](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/multi-friend-selector) in a [Facebox](http://github.com/defunkt/facebox/blob/master/facebox.js) (don't want to use fb:dialog as it pops a new window). The problem I'm having probably stems from escaping quotation marks in javascript, but I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure it out.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
$('#test_button').click(function(){
$.facebox(
    "<div id='box'>" +  
        "<fb:serverfbml width='615'>" +
          "<script type='text/fbml'>" +
            "<fb:request-form action='http://example.com/'" +
                "method='POST'" +
                "invite='true'" +
                "type='Example'" + 
                "content=""Echo Content. <fb:req-choice url=""http://example.com/""     label=""Example Label"" />"">" +
            "<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder='false'" +
                "bypass='cancel'" +
                "cols=4" +
                    "actiontext='Invite Friends To Example'/>" +
            "</fb:request-form>" +
          "</script>" +
        "</fb:serverfbml>" +            
    "</div>"
);
});
```

**Note:** I substituted all of the example.com stuff for the purposes of this post. The multi-friend-selector code works fine when taken out of the Facebox string.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone how may be having the same issue, this is the combo that worked in the end. Thanks to @serg for helping me find my way through some different alternatives.

```
<div id='invite_button'><button type='button' id='test_button'>Add Friends</button></div>

<div id='outside_invite_box' style='display:none;'>     
    {% include 'poigsocial/fb_invite_friends.html' %}
</div>

<!-- Contents of fb_invite_friends.html -->
<div id='inside_invite_box'>    
<fb:serverfbml width="615">
    <script type="text/fbml">
        <fb:request-form action="http://example.com/"
            method="POST"
            invite="true"
            type="Example"
            content="Blah Blah Blah <fb:req-choice url='http://example.com/' label='Join' />">
            <fb:multi-friend-selector showborder="false"
                bypass="cancel"
                cols=4
                rows=4
                actiontext="Invite Facebook Friends"/>
        </fb:request-form>
    </script>
</fb:serverfbml>            
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#test_button').click(function(){
        $.facebox({ div: '#inside_invite_box' }, 'invite_lightbox');        
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide the full solution (e.g. an jsfiddle) ? I'm trying to integrate an invite friend modal into my website but can't get it working. You seem to use jquery but I see no reference to jquery lib into your code.

Answer (score 4):

`<fb:serverfbml>` tag must be present on a page from the beginning, you can't add it dynamically. Everything inside it can be dynamic though.

So assign `<fb:serverfbml>` some id and then load your fbml inside it when needed.

On the page:

```
<div id='box'>
    <fb:serverfbml width='615' id='invite_box'></fb:serverfbml>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#test_button').click(function(){
    $("#invite_box").html(
          "<script type='text/fbml'>" +
            "<fb:request-form action='http://example.com/'" +
                "method='POST'" +
                "invite='true'" +
                "type='Example'" + 
                "content=""Echo Content. <fb:req-choice url=""http://example.com/""     label=""Example Label"" />"">" +
            "<fb:multi-friend-selector showborder='false'" +
                "bypass='cancel'" +
                "cols=4" +
                    "actiontext='Invite Friends To Example'/>" +
            "</fb:request-form>" +
          "</script>"
    );

});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Try to disable auto fbml parsing in fb init:

```
FB.init({xfbml: false});
```

and then manually parse fbml after load:

```
$('#test_button').click(function(){
    $("#invite_box").html(...);
    FB.XFBML.parse($("#box")[0]);
});
```

If that doesn't work try to remove `<script type='text/fbml'></script>` wrapper from your fbml (I don't have it in my code, works fine without it).

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm pretty new to javascript, jquery & fbml, and can't say I fully understand this. I tried creating empty tags:  <fb:serverfbml width='615' id='invite_box'></fb:serverfbml> and then putting everything from <script type="text/fbml"> down in a div with id='inside_fbml' Next I added $('#invite_box').load("#inside_fbml"); in the click event for a button, but loads of errors ensued. Do you have any more guidance / a code sample? Thanks again.

Comment: @Joe see the update. Also your line `content=""Echo Content...` looks like needs some quote masking.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. Unfortunately, the console now shows this error: **<fb:serverfbml> requires the "fbml" attribute.** I tried putting the <script type='text/fbml'> tag in the html on the page, but still get it. This issue appears to have stumped others, as well: http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/issues/issue/83

Comment: One other issue with my code above (for future readers) is that you can't include </script> in a string literal without escaping the slash: "<\/script>" is the correct way to include it.

Answer (score 0):

I know that my answer comes pretty late, but you can try loading it as an external html in a hidden iframe. Then just show this iframe within the facebox like this:

```
<iframe src="multiselector.html" id="invite" style="display:none;width:624px; height:485px; border:0;"></iframe>

<a href="#invite" rel="facebox">invite friends</a>
```

There's a lot of inline attributes in the snippet but that's only intended for showing its properties.

Hope it helps.